# Error in lightning:overlayLibrary. PromiseRejection: Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined

Tags: modal, lightning-overlaylibrary

I'm trying to add a modal to my lightning component, but receiving below error.

**Home Component**

```
<aura:component access="global" >
    <lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib"/>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" aura:id="Home" value="Home" onclick="{! c.CL_Operation}">Home</lightning:button>
</aura:component>
```

**Home Controller**

```
CL_Operation : function(component, event, helper) {  

       var modalBody;
        $A.createComponent("c:CL_ModalPopUp", {},
           function(content, status) {
               alert("Content : " + content);

               if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                   modalBody = content;

                   alert("Modal Body :" + modalBody );

                   component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal({
                       header: "Application Confirmation",
                       body: modalBody,
                       showCloseButton: true,


                   })
               }
               else{
                   console.log("not successful");
               }
        });



   },
```

**Modal Component**

This is the component I want see on above button click.

```
<aura:component access="global" >
    <div>
        Confirm Navigation:
        Are you sure you want to leave this form? All data in the form will be lost.
    </div>
    <div>
        Leave Form
    </div>
    <div>
        Stay on Form
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

But on the button click I receive the below error message. 
**[PromiseRejection: [Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined]]]**

Any thoughts on how to get rid of this error are greatly appreciated.

Thanks...!

Answer (score 1):

lightning:overlayLibrary does not work in aura:application.

Use component inside any component in Lightning App Builder, where it works.